# iText7 not showing filled form fields, barcodes in Adobe Acrobat

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

I'm trying to use itext7 to do a mail-merge on a pdf form, but when I open the form in Adobe, the fields aren't filled in.

Opening the same form in Chrome shows the filled fields.

Additionally, there's a calculated barcode on the form, which once again breaks after going through itext7 in Adobe, but not Chrome, even if I don't update the barcode form field.

Does anyone have any ideas if there's a flag I am meant to be setting, or if this is a known issue with itext7?

The form I'm trying to merge is the [US g-28 form (Google Drive link)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5ivomly37l5VzJfRUFBUUJlZVU/view?usp=sharing).

For some reason, the current version on the [government website](https://www.uscis.gov/g-28) is missing the barcode at the moment, but it's the same form otherwise.

I'm trying to determine if it's a problem with itext7, or with my code, so I know if I should be evaluating a different PDF library instead.

```cs
using iText.Forms;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace PDF_Merge
{
    public class pdf_merge_txt
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // args = new[] { "form.pdf", "data.txt" }

            var filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(args[0]);
            var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(args[0]);
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(args[0]);

            if (args.Length == 2)
            {
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(args[1], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    var outfile = Path.ChangeExtension(args[1], "pdf");
                    var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(args[0]).SetUnethicalReading(true), new PdfWriter(outfile));
                    var form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);

                    form.SetGenerateAppearance(true);

                    var fields = form.GetFormFields();

                    foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(args[1]))
                    {
                        var parts = line.Trim().Split(new[] { ":=" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                        var field = fields.Where(f => f.Key.EndsWith(parts[0])).OrderBy(f => f.Key.Length).Select(f => f.Value).FirstOrDefault();

                        if (field != null)
                        {
                            field.SetValue(parts[1].Trim());
                        }
                    }

                    pdfDoc.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The data.txt looks like this:

```
form1[0].#subform[0].Line6_EMail[0]:=email@address.com
form1[0].#subform[0].Line4_DaytimeTelephoneNumber[0]:=123456789
form1[0].#subform[0].Line7_MobileTelephoneNumber[0]:=0987654321
form1[0].#subform[0].Line2c_MiddleName[0]:=Anon
form1[0].#subform[0].Line2b_GivenName[0]:=John
form1[0].#subform[0].Line2a_FamilyName[0]:=Doe
```

Comment: Most likely you have a hybrid form (both AcroForm and XFA). Remove the xfa part should do.

Comment: @mkl I tried that after posting this, with no luck.

Comment: I just tested it. With your copy of the document a `form.RemoveXfaForm()` sufficed, for the document from the government site additionally a `pdfDoc.GetCatalog().Remove(PdfName.Perms)` was necessary.

Comment: Cf. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44110012/1729265).