# iText 7 .NET makes my fields readonly automatically

Tags: .net, pdf, itext7

I am fairly new to iText.
I downloaded a free 30 day trial and tried the following on .NET MVC:
1. Extract fields from PDF form:

```
string src = "mypdf.pdf";
string dest = "mypdfRES.pdf";
PdfReader newReader = new PdfReader(src);
newReader.SetUnethicalReading(true);
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(newReader, new PdfWriter(dest));
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, true);
IDictionary<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetFormFields();
```

After that I set a value to a specific field

```
PdfFormField toSet;
fields.TryGetValue("form1[0].#subform[0].Line1_FamilyName[0]", out toSet); 
toSet.SetValue("Test familyname");
pdf.Close();
```

Now when I open up the newly saved PDF document mypdfRES.pdf all of fields are blank.

Please suggest why is iText automatically setting all my form fields to read-only.

PS. Link to the pdf document used in this test https://www.uscis.gov/system/files_force/files/form/i-765.pdf?download=1

Comment: Please share a PDF file that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AlexeySubach here is the link https://www.uscis.gov/system/files_force/files/form/i-765.pdf?download=1

Comment: **A** Your form is a hybrid XFA form. This type of form may require special treatment. **B** Your document contains a usage rights signature. To not invalidate it, you have to edit it using an incremental update.

Comment: Which version of iText exactly do you use? I just tested your code as is and the family name clearly was set, that field was not blank. (Adobe Reader complained about the invalidated usage rights signature, but that is to be expected.)

Comment: @AlexeySubach The file also is encrypted. I tried to edit it in append mode but `new StampingProperties().useAppendMode()` and also `new StampingProperties().preserveEncryption().useAppendMode()` resulted in invalid PDFs Adobe Reader does not even open. You might want to look into that.

Comment: @mkl thanks for additional info, we are looking into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDF in question has three properties which make filling in more difficult:

1. The form definition in it is a hybrid XFA / AcroForm definition pair.
2. The file is signed using a usage rights (**UR3**) signature required by the XFA form for saving.
3. The file is encrypted.

Usually one can fill in such forms without encryption (item 3) by creating an incremental update, i.e. by working in append mode using `new StampingProperties().useAppendMode()`. This keeps the usage rights signature valid and everything works fine.

Unfortunately for this encrypted file `new StampingProperties().useAppendMode()` and even `new StampingProperties().preserveEncryption().useAppendMode()` results in broken files. This might be related to the fact that `newReader.SetUnethicalReading(true)` is used instead of supplying the owner password; but supplying the owner password hardly can be expected while filling in a government form... ;*)

A way to proceed with this form anyways is to

- remove the encryption,
- remove the usage rights signature (which has been broken by removing the encryption), and
- remove the XFA form definition (which after the removal of the usage rights signature does not work properly anymore).

The result is a PDF with a pure AcroForm form which you can handle as you wish.

Your code as is already implicitly removes the encryption. To do the other two steps, simply add

```
form.RemoveXfaForm();
pdf.GetCatalog().Remove(PdfName.Perms);
```

before the `pdf.Close()`.

(Tested with iText for .Net version 7.0.2.2 and iText for Java version 7.0.3-SNAPSHOT)